# Make facebook app page posts visible to the public

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, restfb

We have several facebook community pages and an app for updating them. We are using restfb to update the pages.

On privacy we have set everything public as per:

1. https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-make-my-Facebook-Timeline-visible-to-the-public
2. https://faq.buffer.com/article/267-how-do-i-adjust-the-visibility-of-my-facebook-posts

When we login and check the posts the privacy icon on right shows each of the posts is public.

However, none on the the posts we have are visible to the public.

Any idea?

Comment: You need to set your app itself “public” in the app dashboard ...

Answer (score 1):

It appears for posts from facebook app to be public the app must be in production/live mode:

1. Load the apps page - http://developers.facebook.com/
2. Select the app to be used (from  drop down on  top left)
3. Click 'App Review' on  left side
4. Change app from 'development' to 'live' under 'Make ... public?'

After that posts made the app to facebook becomes are viewable by public.

Comment: If this solved the problem, you can accept your own answer as the answer to the question so that others know it was the right solution